# zbar IOS screen freezes

Tags: iphone, ios7, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am integrating zbar in my iphone application and below is the code for scanning the barcode.

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

[self presentModalViewController: reader
                            animated: YES];
```

On completion, i will do the following.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)

        break;
    // Do what ever u want
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

The problem with this is, i am using IOS7 and its scanning perfectly in the first instance, however, for the second instance, after it scans, it wont proceed further, even the cancel button wont work and the screen remains in camera mode. I read its an issue with cpu and memory for IOS7 but could not figure out how it can be rectified in my case. Kindly give your valuable inputs.

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up writing my own controller for ZBarReaderView. It wasn't that difficult to do, to get basic functionality at least. You may want to give that a try. (I'm at work right now, but I've emailed myself a note to find my code when I get home. I'll post it when I can, if you think it will help.)

Comment: Thanks a ton mate, will be looking forward to get ur hrlp!! Please do post so that it will hep many like me!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first, please ignore the comment I made about subclassing ZBarReaderView. It was a while ago that I was having problems, and even though I remember trying that, that was not the solution I settled for. I have a couple of suggestions for you.

In the bit of code on top after `presentViewController:animated:` try setting the pointer to the `reader` to nil. I do the following:

```
[self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];
reader = nil;
```

The view controller you're presenting will be holding onto the reader, so don't worry about losing the reference. I think this actually helps with memory. (And, when you're having a problem where things work at first and then fail after doing them more than once, that's often a memory issue.)

Apart from that, in the top bit, I turn off all the symbols, and then enable only the ones I'm interested in. For example, I might do something like this:

```
// Enable only ISBN-13 & ISBN-10 barcodes
[scanner setSymbology:0 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_EAN13 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1];
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_ISBN10 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1];
```

Give these two suggestions a try, especially the first one about setting the reference to nil. That may help.

Comment: Hello Mario, thanks for the detailed response. Tried with both the suggestions given above. But, i still have the same issue, here are my findings. First time i scan, the green color rectangular bar comes, captures isbn and comes out. Second time i scan, the green color bar comes, immediately disappears and screen hangs. cant change the orientation as well. When i try to delete the app, it returns to that frozen screen. Could you please suggest how to close the scanner once the job is done and oblige

Comment: It's a little tough to figure out, because I don't see a problem with the code you posted. So, I've got two things for you. First, have you tried building the simplest toy application that uses the scanner the way you want to use it? Whether or not your simple app reproduces the problem, doing that should make it easier to isolate the problem. (I'm guessing the problem is in code you haven't posted.) If you reproduce the issue in a very simple app, you could post the entire thing on Github or something, and let others take a look. Second, what version of the ZBar SDK are you using?